# Big O /Right or wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I have to decide, wether the following theorem is right or wrong.
There are functions, that satisfy the following conditions:

$ f(n) \in \mathcal{O}(h(n)) $ and $ g(n) \in \mathcal{O}(h(n))$

Now it should hold: $$ \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} =\mathcal{O}(1) $$

By definition I get: $f(n) \leq  c_1 \cdot h(n) \ \forall n\geq N$ and $g(n) \leq  c_2 \cdot h(n) \ \forall n\geq N'$

So, $$  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{c_1}{c_2}  \cdot 1 \ \forall n\geq max\{N,N'\}$$

I'm not sure. g(n) could be 0. What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand why you went from saying f and g are *elements of* O(something) to f/g being *equal to* O(1). O(1) is a set, and f/g is a function, so surely the question is whether it is an element of O(1), right? Was this a typo? Can you explain the question more clearly?

Comment: @EricLippert It is extremely common in big O notation to mix and match the element symbol and equality symbol. They both mean element of. Yes it's very confusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't go from $f \leqslant c_1 h$ and $g \leqslant c_2 h$ to $\frac{f}{g} = \frac{c_1}{c_2}$.

And the initial claim is false. Take, for example, $f(n) = h(n) = n^2$, $g(n) = n$.

Comment: Why can't I go to $ \frac{f}{g}$

Comment: Because why you would? Even with just numbers, no functions: $1 < 2$, $3 < 4$ but $\frac{1}{3} \neq \frac{2}{4}$. May be you wanted to write $\frac{f}{g} \leqslant \frac{c_1}{c_2}$? It's still not true: you  have $\frac{1}{g} \geqslant \frac{1}{c_2 h}$, but you can multiply inequalities only with same direction.

Comment: Ok thank you. Now I see my mistake:)

Answer (score 8):

Consider $f(n)=h(n)=1$ and $g(n)=1/n$.